# Handling null WMI query in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am trying to handle the case where `colItems` will be null because the Computer does not have the WMI class Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack. However all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Here is my working code without the null check:

```
Set oWsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
Set oWshSysEnv = oWsh.Environment("PROCESS")   
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")   
Set colItems = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select AvailableLicenses,IssuedLicenses,ProductVersion,TypeAndModel from Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack")
For Each objItem In colItems     
strTS = objItem.ProductVersion & " | " & objItem.TypeAndModel & " | " & objItem.AvailableLicenses & " | " & objItem.IssuedLicenses
wscript.echo strTS
Next
```

I have been trying functions such as `IsEmpty`, `IsObject` or `If` with `<> ""` but again without success.

As suggested in a comment, I tried `If not colItems is nothing then`

But if I do that I obtain the following error for the following code:

```
 Set oWsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
    Set oWshSysEnv = oWsh.Environment("PROCESS")   
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")   
    Set colItems = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select AvailableLicenses,IssuedLicenses,ProductVersion,TypeAndModel from Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack")
    
    If not colItems is nothing then
        For Each objItem In colItems     
        strTS = objItem.ProductVersion & " | " & objItem.TypeAndModel & " | " & objItem.AvailableLicenses & " | " & objItem.IssuedLicenses
        wscript.echo strTS
        Next
    Else
    wscript.echo "is empty"
    End If
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `If not colItems is nothing then`?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @tripleee it's not a great image either, it crops the actual error description.

Comment: Are you positive the `colItems` is returning `null`? If it still runs the `For` loop after an `Is Nothing` check you still have an object reference, so maybe try `.Count > 0` as the duplicate suggests...

Comment: You also get the WMI service object twice, but in a different way, what is up with that? (`GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") ` vs `GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2")` And you don't even seem to use the first one.

Comment: @GeertBellekens That comes from copying code blindly and just copying and pasting things hoping it will work.

Comment: Hey guys. Ok as everyone seems to be tensed, let me explain myself. I did not know for the best practices about screenshots of errors, my bad. I did not post the first line of the error because there was nothing meaningful in it except the path to the vbs file with my profile name in it.
For the WMI service object called two times thank you ! Indeed I assembled two working scripts that I had and missed this part ! Who never did it ?

Regarding the .count it does work and I am putting it as a solution of this post.

Thank you all and cheers

Comment: @Wawa41 you’re welcome btw.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code with the .count function as suggested by lankymarte

```
Set oWsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
Set oWshSysEnv = oWsh.Environment("PROCESS")  
Set colItems = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select AvailableLicenses,IssuedLicenses,ProductVersion,TypeAndModel from Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack")

dim i: i = getCount(colItems)

if (i < 0) then
    wscript.echo "empty"
else
    For Each objItem In colItems     
    strTS = objItem.ProductVersion & " | " & objItem.TypeAndModel & " | " & objItem.AvailableLicenses & " | " & objItem.IssuedLicenses
    wscript.echo strTS
    Next
end if

function getCount(wmiCol)
    on error resume next
    getCount = colItems.Count
    if (err.number <> 0) then getCount = (-1)
    on error goto 0
end function
```